# Replace every nth instance of character in string

Tags: regex, string, go, replace

I'm a bit new to Go, but I'm trying to replace every nth instance of my string with a comma. So for example, a part of my data looks as follows:

```
"2017-06-01T09:15:00+0530",1634.05,1635.95,1632.25,1632.25,769,"2017-06-01T09:16:00+0530",1632.25,1634.9,1631.65,1633.5,506,"2017-06-01T09:17:00+0530",1633.5,1639.95,1633.5,1638.4,991,
```

I want to replace `every 6th comma` with a `'\n'` so it looks like

```
"2017-06-01T09:15:00+0530",1634.05,1635.95,1632.25,1632.25,769"
"2017-06-01T09:16:00+0530",1632.25,1634.9,1631.65,1633.5,506"
"2017-06-01T09:17:00+0530",1633.5,1639.95,1633.5,1638.4,991"
```

I've looked at the `regexp` package and that just seems to be a finder. The `strings` package does have a replace but I don't know how to use it to replace specific indices. I also don't know how to find specific indices without going through the entire string character by character. I was wondering if there is a regEx solution that is more elegant than me writing a helper function.
Strings are immutable so I'm not able to edit them in place.

EDIT: Cast the string into []bytes. This allows me to edit the string in place. Then the rest is a fairly simple for loop, where `dat` is the data.

Comment: Please post what you tried, and explain what the issues is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. I initially had the data as a `string`, but if I cast it to a `byte[]` then I can update it in place.

This allowed me to use a simple `for` loop below to solve the issue without relying on any other metric other than nth character instance

```
for i := 0; i < len(dat); i++ {
    if dat[i] == ',' {
        count += 1
    }
    if count%6 == 0 && dat[i] == ',' {
        dat[i] = '\n'
        count = 0
    }
```

Comment: when processing strings consider it as []rune in these kid of scenarios

Comment: Why would rune be more preferable?

Comment: what you might think of as a character constant is called a `rune` constant in Go.  rune can contain one whole unicode character(32bit) whereas byte can hold only 8 bytes .For strngs with only ASCII characters treating string as []byte is fine but it fails when it has other unicode characters

Answer (score 1):

If that is your input, you should replace `,"` strings with `\n"`.You may use [`strings.Replace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) for this. This will leave a last, trailing comma which you can remove with a slicing.

Solution:

```
in := `"2017-06-01T09:15:00+0530",1634.05,1635.95,1632.25,1632.25,769,"2017-06-01T09:16:00+0530",1632.25,1634.9,1631.65,1633.5,506,"2017-06-01T09:17:00+0530",1633.5,1639.95,1633.5,1638.4,991,`
out := strings.Replace(in, ",\"", "\n\"", -1)
out = out[:len(out)-1]
fmt.Println(out)
```

Output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lb5ZrdLcwa)):

```
"2017-06-01T09:15:00+0530",1634.05,1635.95,1632.25,1632.25,769
"2017-06-01T09:16:00+0530",1632.25,1634.9,1631.65,1633.5,506
"2017-06-01T09:17:00+0530",1633.5,1639.95,1633.5,1638.4,991
```

Comment: Thanks! couple of things: (1) how exactly is the Replace function working in this context. I don't see a `\"` in my string in a pattern, so what exactly is it finding each time to replace. (2) there were still commas at the end of each line in my file; is there a way to remove from end of each line?

Comment: @S2C It's an [interpreted string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals), `\"` means a single quotation mark (because the quotation mark itself would mean the end of the string literal). It finds `,"` texts and replaces them with a newline plus a quotation mark. Exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I see you're exploiting the fact that the comma I want to replace with a new line always has a quote after it. While this works in this context, there are other contexts that I have to do something similar where the only constant pattern is that the nth instance of the character is to be replaced.

Comment: And `string.Replace()` takes a string to replace in, next the part to replace, next what to replace with, and last how many replacements you want. `-1` means no limit.

Comment: @S2C And yes, I've exploited the structure of your input, so that the solution is quite simple. This is not a general "nth replacer".

Answer (score 1):

If you want flexible.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input := `"2017-06-01T09:15:00+0530",1634.05,1635.95,1632.25,1632.25,769,"2017-06-01T09:16:00+0530",1632.25,1634.9,1631.65,1633.5,506,"2017-06-01T09:17:00+0530",1633.5,1639.95,1633.5,1638.4,991,`
    var result []string

    for len(input) > 0 {
        token := strings.SplitN(input, ",", 7)
        s := strings.Join(token[0:6], ",")
        result = append(result, s)
        input = input[len(s):]
        input = strings.Trim(input, ",")
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/mm63Hx24ne